# Multiple Child Objects in single SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have two objects (Test1 and Test2) which have a lookup relationship to "Test 3".

I need a single query to fetch the test1, test2 records by test 3 ID. Heres what I've tried:

```
select id, name from test1, (select id, name from test2) where test3='3123'
```

Comment: The fundamentals of SOQL relationship queries are [explained here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using)

Answer (score 14):

You can write like this:

In your case "Test3" is parent,"test1" and "test2" are childs.

***Try below query***,

```
[select id,name,(select id,name from test1s__r),(select id,name from test2s__r) from test3__c]
```

***For Example***

```
 SELECT id,(SELECT Id,Status,CaseNumber FROM Cases),(SELECT Id,Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

Comment: Yes this is the way you can get multiple child records. Note that here you can see __r instead of __c that's because tfor relationship query you need to mention __r for related object records

Comment: thanks for that.i need these data in EXCEL format .how can i get it

Comment: This is the same requirement where i need the above query result in Excel format

Comment: No i need a result needs to be come in excel without copy paste of data